# Fetch call returns react index.html and chrome gives error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from my local express server, and display it with react, but it seems that the index.html of the react app is being returned. If I check the network tab in the console and it shows that there is a fetch request with the name "projects/" and when I hover over it it shows "http://localhost:3000/api/projects". The console indicates that the problem is in line 13 of the react file which is "fetch('/api/projects/')". I've been trying for a while to fix this but can't seem to get it right. Code below

**Express:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

let projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "project1",
    description: "One - description",
    url: "www.One.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "project2",
    description: "Two - description",
    url: "www.Two.com"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "project3",
    description: "Three - description",
    url: "www.Three.com"
  }
];

app.get("/api/projects", (req, res) => {
  res.json(projects);
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**React:**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      projects: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/projects/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(projects =>
        this.setState({ projects }, () =>
          console.log("Projects fetched...", projects)
        )
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**React package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-full-stack-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're fetching `/api/projects/`. Your `app.use` is `/api/projects` (no trailing `/`). Perhaps that's it?

Comment: Just tried that, still returns the same error @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Ah, well... One hoped. :-)

Comment: What do you see in the network tab when the problem occurs?

Comment: I've just recreated your project and I'm unable to reproduce. The console logs the 3 projects. Did you restart your `npm run start` after setting the proxy?

Comment: I suspect the problem is an HTTP error. Unfortunately, your code -- like the code of so many! -- falls prey to the `fetch` API footgun: `fetch` doesn't reject the promise on HTTP error, only on network error. Check `ok` or `status` before calling `json`, you're probably getting an error. More: [Common `fetch errors](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - my network tab shows that there is a fetch request with the name "projects/" and when i hover over it it shows "http://localhost:3000/api/projects". Will check that out, thank you for your help!

Comment: @yuriy636 - yes i did

Comment: Please use copy and paste to show us the **exact** error you get, with both origins. Fundamentally, if you're on a page served from `http://localhost:3000` and you try to load `http://localhost:3000/api/projects/`, that's fine, it's not a cross-origin request. But if one of them is using 3000 and the other is using 5000, it's a cross-origin request you're not set up to handle, which is why you get the error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - i just installed the cors middleware and added it my express file and it is working perfectly now!!! Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: @begdev - My pleasure! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your server is running on port 5000 and the client on port 3000. So, you have to call the api request as
`fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/projects/')`

If you don't specify the full URL, the request will be sent to `http://localhost:3000/api/projects`

You can also store the base URL in a constant.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      projects: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/projects/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(projects => this.setState({ projects }, () => console.log('Projects fetched...', projects)));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but they are using `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

Comment: So i specified the full URL and got this errors in the console: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/projects/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. Yeah i have added the proxy but i'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: @begdev - So Ajay is correct, it's an SOP problem, your setup isn't allowing a cross-origin call. [It also means [my guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981189/fetch-call-returns-react-index-html-and-chrome-gives-error-uncaught-in-promise?noredirect=1#comment111374743_62981189) was right. ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a cross-origin request. I installed the cors middleware, following the steps in the expressjs documentation, and added it to my express file and used app.use(cors()). Everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this in, I know this has been answered, but I encountered this problem and was spinning my wheels for a while on it, despite all the solutions. Here is how I figured out to make it work:

- I was a bit confused about the ports to use, as the app opens in port 3000, even though I had specified 5000 for my Express server. So I changed all ports everywhere to 3000 to try it out.
- then I restarted my server first, then my react app, and it asked me if I wanted to open it on another port because 3000 was already being used. I said yes, and viola, it works. It now opens on port 3001 and everything works beautifully.

Code below to help any who may come to this page later, like I did.

server.js (express):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        user: "",
        password: "",
        database: "",
    },
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
// CORS implemented so that we don't get errors when trying to access the server from a different server location
app.use(cors());
// GET: Fetch all movies from the database

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.select('*')
        .from('cards')
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`));
```

React App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAPI = () => {
            const API = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
            fetch(API)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    setLoading(false);
                    setApiData(data);
                });
        };
        getAPI();
    }, []);

    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    return (
        ..... react stuff here .....
    );
};
export default App;
```